# udev rule not working

Tags: usb-drive, udev

I cannot figure out why this rule wont fire:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sdb", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="Elements 1048*", RUN+="/usr/bin/mysync.sh"
```

here is the additional info

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb':
    KERNEL=="sdb"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="976769024"
    ATTR{stat}=="    2424   116950   120088     5572        1        0        1      388        0     3152     5940"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{events}==""
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{removable}=="0"
    ATTR{capability}=="50"
    ATTR{events_async}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="5:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{rev}=="1022"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="7"
    ATTRS{model}=="Elements 1048   "
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x9a8"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x9a8"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x13"
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="WD      "
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host5/target5:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target5:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host5':
    KERNELS=="host5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="MSC Bulk-Only Transport"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1058"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}=="USB Mass Storage"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="1022"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="575856314535334E5A533833"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="7511"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Western Digital"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="1048"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="Elements 1048"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="8"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.7"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="96"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.7"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
    ATTRS{irq}=="22"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1025"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{enabled}=="1"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x27cc"
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0349"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `"sdb*"` as suggested in these [usb automount](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/automounting+usb+flash+drives+on+linux+with+udev+and+pmount) rules.

Also be sure to ensure your `/usr/bin/mysync.sh` is marked executable, an that it starts with an appropriate shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/sh`)